# AJAX query does not have correct reference to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scope

This is my code:

```js
$('.store-card').each(function() {
  placeid = $(this).data('placeid');
  latlng = $(this).data('latlng');

  card = this;
  console.log("1 ", card);

  $.ajax({
    url: '/stores/placeid/',
    method: "GET",
    data: {
      placeid: placeid
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(card);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The problem here is that by the time the AJAX queries return a response, the refernce to `card` has already changed, hence `card` will always have the value of the last item.

This the console output:

```
    1  <div class="store-card" data-map="#slink-10" data-timing="#stmg-10" data-openhours="#sopen-10" data-placeid="ChIJTZD7ufceDTkRXZdMW4ObIM4" data-latlng="">
    1  <div class="store-card" data-map="#slink-9" data-timing="#stmg-9" data-openhours="#sopen-9" data-placeid="ChIJK-bJgRwDDTkR5vzdTwSc7JI" data-latlng="">
    1  <div class="store-card" data-map="#slink-22" data-timing="#stmg-22" data-openhours="#sopen-22" data-placeid="ChIJk2W43rPjDDkRMeRmDOo8QT8" data-latlng="">
    1  <div class="store-card" data-map="#slink-11" data-timing="#stmg-11" data-openhours="#sopen-11" data-placeid="ChIJebql01D7DDkRMELWwmmpS_A" data-latlng="">
    <div class="store-card" data-map="#slink-11" data-timing="#stmg-11" data-openhours="#sopen-11" data-placeid="ChIJebql01D7DDkRMELWwmmpS_A" data-latlng="">
    <div class="store-card" data-map="#slink-11" data-timing="#stmg-11" data-openhours="#sopen-11" data-placeid="ChIJebql01D7DDkRMELWwmmpS_A" data-latlng="">
    <div class="store-card" data-map="#slink-11" data-timing="#stmg-11" data-openhours="#sopen-11" data-placeid="ChIJebql01D7DDkRMELWwmmpS_A" data-latlng="">
    <div class="store-card" data-map="#slink-11" data-timing="#stmg-11" data-openhours="#sopen-11" data-placeid="ChIJebql01D7DDkRMELWwmmpS_A" data-latlng="">
```

How can I ensure that each `$.ajax` will have the corresponding reference to `card` rather than the latest reference?

Comment: Dont forget add `var` when you declare variables!

Comment: Use `type : "GET"` in place of `method : "GET"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not forget to add `var` to all first time declared variables!

So try change code to this:

```
var placeid = $(this).data('placeid');
var latlng = $(this).data('latlng');

var card = this;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
var card = this;
```

in your code snipped, then it's a local variable which gets bound in the closure.
In your code it's a global variable (= window.card) that can get changed by other code.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `context` of `$.ajax()` to `this`

```
$.ajax({
  context: this
})
.then(function() {
  // `this` : `this` within `.each()`
})
```